# Mysql FETCH CURSOR result ununderstood

Tags: mysql, cursor, fetch

I've been Googleing around for a while and I am sure that the problem is that I don't understand clearly how CURSORs in MySQL work.

A short explanation of the problem: I'm writing such function (simplified):

```
CREATE DEFINER=`me`@`localhost` FUNCTION `product_move`(prID INT, tr_type VARCHAR(2), clID INT, am INT, dnID INT, usrID INT, price FLOAT(10,2), ti DATETIME, barc TINYTEXT, cmt TINYTEXT, lnID INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE cur_id INT;
    DECLARE net_pr FLOAT(10,2);
    DECLARE cur_r INT;
    DECLARE remaind INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE avg_price FLOAT(10,2) DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR SELECT  `products_transactionsID`,
                                                `price`,
                                                `remains`
                                        FROM `products_transactions`
                                        WHERE `productID`=prID AND `remains`>0 AND `type`='V'
                                        ORDER BY `products_transactionsID` ASC;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
 OPEN curs;
           SET remaind=am;
           read_loop:LOOP
                FETCH curs INTO cur_id,net_pr,cur_r;
                 IF done THEN
                  LEAVE read_loop;
                END IF;
                IF (cur_r>=remaind) THEN
                    SET avg_price = avg_price + (net_pr * remaind);
                    UPDATE `products_transactions` SET `remains`=`remains`-remaind WHERE products_transactionsID=cur_id;
                    LEAVE read_loop;
                ELSE

                    SET avg_price = avg_price + (net_pr * cur_r);
                    SET remaind=remaind-cur_r;
                    UPDATE `products_transactions` SET `remains`=0 WHERE products_transactionsID=cur_id;
                END IF;
           END LOOP;

CLOSE curs;
           SET avg_price=avg_price/am;
 INSERT INTO products_transactions
                       (`products_transactionsID`,`clientID`,`date_created`,`delivery_notesID`,`type`,`productID`,`amountIN`,`amountOUT`,`barcodes`,`in_stock`,`out_stock`,`out_repair`,`out_loss`,`booked`,`ordered`,`userID`,`price`,`comments`,`fifo_buy_price`)
                   SELECT NULL, clID, ti, dnID , tr_type, prID, 0, am, barc, products_transactions.in_stock-am, products_transactions.out_stock,
                       products_transactions.out_repair, products_transactions.out_loss, products_transactions.booked, products_transactions.ordered,usrID,price,cmt,avg_price
                   FROM
                       products_transactions WHERE productID=prID ORDER BY products_transactionsID DESC LIMIT 1;
```

So, we insert a new row in this table, based upon some calculations from the previously selected rows and updating these rows meanwhile.

The problem is with the `avg_price` variable, which should be calculated based on the `net_pr` variable which is FETCH'ed from the cursor. But somehow, instead of being FETCH'ed from the SELECT, the `net_pr` variable takes the value of the `price` input parameter of my function! How is that possible?

My guesses have been so far:

- a variable name conflict? Searched through the code but I can't find any.
- updating the table within the LOOP could make the CURSOR loose its position? It would make sense, but that wouldn't result in this, either...

I'd apreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things that I can see:

1) Don't update the table that you're using in the cursor. MySQL says the cursor is read only but I wouldn't trust this. Set your value, exit the cursor, and then update the table.

2) Using the same name for a variable in the proc definition and a column in a select gives a conflict: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/local-variable-scope.html

"A local variable should not have the same name as a table column. If an SQL statement, such as a SELECT ... INTO statement, contains a reference to a column and a declared local variable with the same name, MySQL currently interprets the reference as the name of a variable. "

Comment: Yes, your 2nd idea solved the problem, thank you!
(btw, updating just works... I don't believe it's safe, but works)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the conflict with local variables. That helped me out a lot.